# Combine two tables with Informatica

Tags: informatica

I am trying to solve an Informatica problem

I have two tables: Table A and Table B have the following structure

Table A

```
A_Key
A_Name
A_Address
A_PostalCode
A_Country
A_Latitude
A_Longitude
```

Table B

```
B_Key
B_Name
B_PostalCode
B_Latitude
B_Longitude
```

I need to combine A & B in order to have one output table that contains all the Attribute of A & B.

Since I am new to Informatica Data Quality tool, I am trying to find the logic how I can implement this.

Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Not sure of `IDQ`, but in Power Center you can do a `Normal Join` based on `Key` or `Name` whichever satisfies your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Joiner Transformation to do this.

It has two groups - Master and Detail. Ideally, you should connect the table with lesser data to the Master and the table with additional data should be connected to Detail section.

Ensure your table data is sorted before connecting to the joiner. Also, enable the Sorted Input in the advanced section of the Joiner Transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Again for powercenter, this scenario sounds more like a union to me and setting the missing colums to null from group b